# Is it reasonable to ask IT to setup a personal intranet website for me?

Tags: software-industry, technology, websites

I'm a data analyst who would really like to have my own website at work on our intranet. I'm tired of trying to having to share documents and trying to work within the confines of common software like Word, Excel, etc. I'd rather be using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript to create and share better quality visualizations.

The problem is that I've never seen or heard of a company allowing an employee to have their own website on the company's intranet. Does anyone know of any precedent for this? Or is just a big security concern and IT departments don't let people do that?

Comment: This is a great question that you should probably ask your manager or a senior member of your team.  You might have better luck if you can get a few people with more leverage in the company to back you up.

Comment: Companies do that all the time. Whether your company has the resources and expertise is a different question.

Comment: This depends on your security policies and also how your company is ran. For example, this would be a big security concern and we would not allow it in our environment. Who would patch, update monitor the website? How are documents secured? Who has access to it? It really depends on how tight your IT department runs your network, but it isn't unprecedented.

Comment: When you say personal website, are you talking about something that would be accessible outside your company, or just available internally?

Comment: @SethR Just available internally.

Comment: You might have more luck asking for a wiki. Or for something like https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence - especially if you can find something free

Comment: I ran a small cluster of Linux machines at RBI one of which was used to host a proof of concept tool - but I had the skills to do  this

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you **create a sample of what you have in mind maybe on your private notebook** (not on a company server and not on an internet server).

Then **show this sample to the relevant people in your office and show them why this is better than the available options**.

If your manager/boss likes it then maybe you can to what you want. If for whatever reason they don't want that you do it they will still see that you are actively looking for a good solution for a work related problem. I guess they will see this in a positive light.

*Be careful that you do this not in your normal work-time and don't use confidential company data on your private notebook. The sample should show your ideas, it does not have to contain real data.*

Comment: bad Idea - don't put company data on your computer

Comment: @Neuromancer if the computer belongs to the company, it's safe to assume that *all data* is company data. I don't think Edgar means 'private' as 'personally belonging to OP' - just as the corporate notebook assigned to the OP.

Answer (score 5):

You can ask IT for anything, they can say no. In terms of what you want to achieve there is a reason people use Word, Excel etc,. For most people it's what they're comfortable with. If you start giving them something else it may be disruptive.

They're very comprehensive applications, if you think you can do better with some CSS and Javascript, you should probably start your own company and start making millions.

Nothing to stop you asking though.

Comment: The problem is that there are many of the best data visualization tools, such as D3.js, which create content which needs to be served by a web server. I have my own web server, but I can't rightly use that to store my company's proprietary data. So I'm stuck needing to use one of my company's web servers. I feel like other people must have run into this issue, but I have never seen someone talk about it.

Comment: Because others use the company tools for many excellent reasons. Nothing to stop you asking, but be prepared for disappointment, as an IT I'd say 'I'll look into it' Then go laugh in my office.

Answer (score -2):

You could ask them to provide an iframe with it's src aimed at a site you control, thereby it would be sandboxed and they wouldn't need to update it or give you access to their systems.

Comment: It is often a very bad idea to use work data of any kind with services outside the intranet if your management hasn't decided to do so. Creating a new system based on some external service (including ones hosted by yourself) is a scary idea for many companies. And often they have good reasons for not trusting services outside.